# Using L Hopital's Rule Using $e$

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

Can someone please help?

I need to use L Hopital's Rule to find the limit:
$$
\lim_\limits{x\to e}\frac{x-e}{\frac xe-1}
$$

I know I need to find the derivative of the top and bottom, but since the derivative of $e$ is $e$, I can't seem to figure out what to do next.

Thank you!

Comment: The derivative of $f(x)=e^x$ is indeed $e^x$, **but the derivative of $f(x)=e$ is $0$, since $e$ is a constant!**

Comment: The ratio of the derivatives is indeed $\frac{1}{1/e} = e$...

Comment: $e=\exp(1) \rightarrow (\exp(1))'=(1)'\cdot\exp(1)=0$ as AndreasT mentioned.

Comment: just do $\frac{x-e}{\frac{x}{e} - \frac{e}{e}} = e$

Comment: +1 for @Alex 's comment. L'Hopital is usually not the best way to tackle a limit problem. In this case a little algebra shows you the function is constant except at the single point where you want the limit.

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of $x-e$ is $1$, because $e$ is a constant. The derivative of $\frac xe-1$ is $\frac1e$ since $\frac1e$ is the coefficient of $x$.  Thus after taking derivatives the ratio becomes $1/\frac1e$ which equals $e$.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize it was a constant!

Comment: No problem, it's a common mistake, no shame.